# How to get ids which does not exist in another listagg | Oracle 19c |

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a query to get values in comma separated format from both the table

Table 1 :

```
SELECT 
    regex_replace(xmlcast(Xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(empid, empid, ',')) AS clob), '\s*,\s*$', '') AS str1
FROM 
    (SELECT empid
     FROM employee);
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT 
    regex_replace(xmlcast(Xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(depid, depid, ',')) AS clob), '\s*,\s*$', '') AS str2
FROM   
    (SELECT depid
     FROM department);
```

Output of both queries:

```
str1 = 1,4,5,6,8
str2 = 1,5,6
```

How do I compare both the `str1` and `str2` and get ids which are in `str1` but not in `str2`

Expected output: `4,8`

Comment: You should not compare string `str1` and `str2`. You should select ids which are in employee  but not in department, then listagg them.

Comment: Why not compare the tables directly, and apply listagg to the differences you find?

Comment: @AlexPoole : To much of data in both tables nearly  `10 lakhs`

Comment: That isn't much data, but even if it was billions of rows, it would still be simpler and almost certainly faster to compare the table data directly then to do expensive and complicated string manipulation. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: This is a good example of XY problem when you create an issue first and are trying to resolve it later. Use set methods for set operations and then aggregate: `minus/not exists`  and `listagg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach considering that both `str1` and `str2` are coming from different tables. Although I consider the comments more than right that this kind of comparison should not be done this way.

```
with x as 
(
select regexp_substr(x.str1,'[^,]+',1,level) as str1_spit 
from ( select '1,4,5,6,8' as str1 from dual ) x 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(x.str1 ,'[,]') + 1 
), 
y as 
( select regexp_substr(y.str2,'[^,]+',1,level) as str2_spit 
from ( select '1,5,6' as str2 from dual ) y 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(y.str2 ,'[,]') + 1 
)
select LISTAGG(str1_spit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by str1_spit) as final_value 
from 
(
select x.str1_spit , y.str2_spit 
from x left join y on x.str1_spit = y.str2_spit 
where y.str2_spit is null
order by x.str1_spit 
)
```

Demo

```
SQL> with x as
  2  (
select regexp_substr(x.str1,'[^,]+',1,level) as str1_spit
from ( select '1,4,5,6,8' as str1 from dual ) x
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(x.str1 ,'[,]') + 1
),
y as
( select regexp_substr(y.str2,'[^,]+',1,level) as str2_spit
from ( select '1,5,6' as str2 from dual ) y
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=REGEXP_COUNT(y.str2 ,'[,]') + 1
)
select LISTAGG(str1_spit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by str1_spit) as final_value
from
(
select x.str1_spit , y.str2_spit
from x left join y on x.str1_spit = y.str2_spit
where y.str2_spit is null
order by x.str1_spit
)  3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19  ;

FINAL_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4,8

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to compare the delimited strings, you can simply use `NOT IN` (or `NOT EXISTS`) and compare the table values:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace( xmlcast(Xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(empid,empid,',')) as clob),'\s*,\s*$','') AS str1
FROM   employee
WHERE  empid NOT IN (
         SELECT depid
         FROM   department
       );
```

However, you should consider whether it makes sense to compare the IDs for employees to the IDs for departments as that does not appear to make logical sense.

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (empid) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE department (depid) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6 FROM DUAL;
```

The query outputs:

> | STR1 |
> | --- |
> | 4,8 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc227daa4c4cdf2848825e0b83df4fa3)*

Comment: Their to much of data in both the tables nearly 10 lakhs. So i got both in str  so that subset can be done any other way to do. Need to do without not in

Comment: @yyy62103 1,000,000 rows is not much data and it will likely be **MUCH** more efficient to compare the tables directly rather than trying to generate delimited strings and then split those string back into rows and compare the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it by comparing strings (don't, use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` and compare the tables) then you can do it by only splitting one of the two strings and using simple string functions (rather than regular expressions, which are an order-of-magnitude slower):

```sql
WITH data (str1, str2) AS (
  SELECT TO_CLOB('1,4,5,6,8'),
         TO_CLOB('1,5,6')
  FROM   DUAL
),
bounds (str1, str2, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT str1,
         str2,
         1,
         INSTR(str1, ',', 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT str1,
         str2,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(str1, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
),
items (item, str2) AS (
  SELECT CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(str1, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(str1, spos, epos - spos)
         END,
         ',' || str2 || ','
  FROM   bounds
  ORDER BY spos
)
SELECT regexp_replace(
         xmlcast(Xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(item,item,',')) as clob),
         '\s*,\s*$'
       ) AS str3
FROM   items
WHERE  str2 NOT LIKE '%,' || item || ',%';
```

Which outputs:

> | STR3 |
> | --- |
> | 4,8 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=733be3979c115363d8d7cf6d7c8d4dc9)*